# convert datetime datetime to numpy int64 python

Tags: python, date

How do I convert type datetime.datetime to type numpy.int64 ?
I have 44346 days, 0:00:00 but I want 44346

```
data_r = xlrd.xldate_as_datetime(int(data_calcolo), 0).date()
    y = data_r.month
    a= data_r.year
    if k > 12 :
       k= k-12
       y =y-k
       a = a-1  
    data_nuova=datetime(a, y, 1)
    z=datetime(1900, 1, 1)
    f=(data_nuova-z)
```

Answer (score 0):

Subtracting two `datetime.datetime` objects (i.e., `data_nuova-z`) returns a [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) object.

If you just want the number of days in that difference, then you can access it using `f.days` and then cast that integer to an `np.int64` object.